# Find counterexample when $p| |G:H|$ about induced representation

Tags: representation-theory

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$ and $k$ is a field of characteristic $p$. If $p\nmid|G:H|$ then the induced module $U\uparrow_H^G$ over $k$ of any semisimple $k[H]$-module $U$ is also a semisimple $k[G]$-module. (This can be shown in the way similar to prove Maschke's Theorem.)

I want to find a counterexample when $p||G:H|$.

Comment: Just take the trivial subgroup.

Comment: So you mean something like $k\uparrow_{1}^{C_{p^3}}\cong k[C_{p^3}]$, this is equivalent to consider the regular representation of $k[x]/\langle x^{p^3}\rangle$ which is indecomposable.

Comment: Is there any example that is not induced from the trivial subgroup?

Comment: Play around with $k=\mathbb{F}_2$, $H=A_3\cong C_3$ and $G=S_3$. What happens when we induce the trivial $H$-module?

Comment: Thanks David, I think I know how to do it. The representation maps identity and 3-cycles to $I_2$ and 2-cycles to $\left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right]$. Over $\mathbb{F}_2$  we can see that there is no basis enable us to simultaneously diagonalize the matrices, probably like this way, right?

Comment: Are there any other ways to see whether the representation is indecomposable while working on examples? I think it is little hard to do it when the degree of the representation become 3 or 4.